# Two ModalViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email, modalviewcontroller

I have a navigationController from where I launch a ModalViewController.
In this ModalViewController I will display the MailComposer which itself another ModalViewController.

Now if the user hits the send button the MailComposerView should be dismissed as well the other ModalViewController. For that I call a delegate method in the mailComposerController.

Now only the MailComposerView will be dismissed but no the the other ModalViewController and I get following error message

```
attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear. self = <UINavigationController: 0x724d500> modalViewController = <UINavigationController: 0x72701f0>
```

Do you have any Idea would I'm doing wrong?

First ModalView

```
- (void)addList {
NSLog(@"addList");

//AddListViewController *addListViewController = [[AddListViewController alloc] init];
AddListViewController *addListViewController = [[AddListViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
addListViewController.delegate = self;

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addListViewController];
navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

[navigationController release];
[addListViewController release];    }
```

In the AddListViewController calling the MailView

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    NSString *subject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Group invite for groupname: %@", @"mhm"];
    [mailComposer setSubject:subject];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *emailBody = @"This is an group invite bla bla";
    [mailComposer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
    [mailComposer release];
```

In the mailComposerController method

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.delegate finishAddList:checkmark andListName:listName.text];
```

In the finsihAddList delegate

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must call the second dismiss with a delay, because the first dismiss hasn't been done yet when called.

```
[self performSelector: @selector(finish:) withObject: obj afterDelay: 0.0f];
```

A delay of 0.0f is intentional, it means it will be done in the next event loop.

Comment: Tried it but still get the same error                                   
[self.delegate performSelector: @selector(finishAddList:) withObject:listName.text afterDelay: 0.0f];

Comment: Have you tried removing animation to the second dismiss? And have you tried with a bigger delay?

Comment: I think it is dangerous to simply use a delay because you are then relying on a parameter you set based on tests you've done with a particular hardware, specifically, with a particular CPU. On slower hardware, or if the CPU is too busy, this delay may still not be enough.

Comment: @HZC it's not about knowledge of hardware, but about knowledge of event loop. The delay works even if set to 0.0f, even if the hardware was absurdly fast, because this will effectively be done on the next run of the event loop.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem. I had a stack of modally presented view controllers. When I tried to dismiss them starting with the visible one, and moving down the stack, I would fail with the same error. The solution was to dismiss the view controller at the bottom of the stack. It would dismiss everything above it.

In your case, my solution would amount to changing the mailComposerController method so that it contains only one line (does not dismiss the top-most modal vie controller).

```
[self.delegate finishAddList:checkmark andListName:listName.text];
```

I know you've resolved your problem already, but thought this might be helpful for others.

Comment: This is a better solution because it doesn't involve timing.