# Closing Parent and Child View Controller

Tags: parent-child

I am trying to figure out how to close both a parent view controller and a child view controller at the same time.  I have created a delegate and can dismiss the child view controller from the parent.   I want to add code to dismiss the parent also so I can return to the main menu.  Any suggestions on what I need to add to dismiss the parent at the same time?

Here is my code:

Child View Controller

```
- (IBAction)endGamePressed:(id)sender 
{
    [delegate pitchCounterViewControllerDidCancel:self];
}
```

Parent View Controller

```
- (void)pitchCounterViewControllerDidCancel:(PitchCounterViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In practice you should try and avoid making a ViewController dismiss itself.

In your `pitchCounterViewControllerDidCancel:` method, you need to make a delegate call (as per the child controller, that is executed by the parent of the Parent View Controller.

Like:

```
- (void)pitchCounterViewControllerDidCancel:(PitchCounterViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    [delegate parentControllerDidFinish:self];
}
```

Comment: Thanks twilson.  You pointed me in the right direction.  It turned out trying to dismiss the parent and the parent of the parent gave me an error.  I removed the dismiss in the parent and I was able to get back to the main view as answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988432/two-modalviewcontroller