# Pop a UINavigationController that was presented modally

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, modal-dialog, modalviewcontroller

I'm working on an iOS 5 application that first presents the user with a Login Window.  Upon successful login, a Modal Segue is performed that presents a UINavigationController which contains the bulk of the actual app.  Now many things can happen from this point on, but what I'm interested in is when the user decides to log out.

I would like to return to the first view, the Login window, but I can't seem to pop the Navigation Controller and return to the first view.

As a visualization:

```
                                             (NavigationController)
[UserLoginViewController] --modal segue-> [UserMenuTableViewController] --push segue--> [otherviews, etc]
     ^                                                  |
     |                                             modal segue
     |                                                  |
     |                                                  v
     ^                                    [UserDashBoardViewController]
     |                                                  |
     |                                           (logout pressed)
     |                                                  |
      -<---------------pop back to login--------------<-
```

I've tried delegation, to notify the initial login view that it's time to dismiss the Navigation Controller that was presented modally, but I get the error:

```
2012-09-10 11:13:05.749 KITxWebMobileJSONv4[1138:f803] attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear. self = <UINavigationController: 0x68c6150> modalViewController = <UserDashboardViewController: 0x68d9fb0>
2012-09-10 11:13:05.749 KITxWebMobileJSONv4[1138:f803] attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear. self = <UserLoginViewController: 0x688ffa0> modalViewController = <UINavigationController: 0x68c6150>
```

The Login View delegation looks like this:

```
// This method is called from the UserMenuTableViewController, when it's time to log out:
- (void)userMenuTableViewController:(UserMenuTableViewController *)sender
                          loggedOut:(BOOL)didLogOut
{
    if (didLogOut) {
        /* delete user info and take care of data on backend:
         * ...
         */

        // pop navigation controller, presenting the initial Login View:
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  // THIS LINE FIRES AND GETS THE ERROR ABOVE
    }
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Login Success"]) {  // successful login:

        // set (UINavigationController *)self.nav to the segue destination (for a handle, if needed):
        self.nav = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;

        // grab the user menu and set self to be it's delegate:
        UserMenuTableViewController *userMenu = [self.nav.viewControllers lastObject];
        userMenu.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your error messages mention `UserDashboardViewController`, but I don't see any other mention of that in your post.  How is `UserDashboardViewController` presented?  What is its relationship with `UserMenuTableViewController`?

Comment: Are you manually popping all the ViewControllers off the NavigationController's stack just before calling dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988432/two-modalviewcontroller) question deals with a similar situation (though admittedly chaining multiple modal ViewControllers) where trying to execute multiple dismiss calls simultaneously was the problem.

Comment: How have you modal segue to the navigationcontroller?

Comment: @robmayoff , `UserDashboardViewController` is another modal view, presented by the NavigationController via tabbar button.  That is where they can choose to log out.  When they do, a message is passed back to the `UserMenuTableViewController` via delegation to dismiss the modal `UserDashboardViewController` and then continue logging out.  That works fine, on logout, all the views in the NavigationController are popped and cleaned up.  It's popping the NavigationController's root view controller (`UserMenuTableViewController`) that isn't happening.

Comment: @Xono , The `UserDashboardViewController` where the user can choose to log out, is only accessible in the NavigationController's root view.  When they touch a bar button, it appears modally and they can log out from there.  If they do, the root view controller (`UserMenuTableViewController`) is told via delegate to dismiss the `UserDashboardViewController`.  That works great.  But now I need to pop the actual NavigationController to return the first View, which presented `UserMenuTableViewController` via modal segue.

Comment: @Neo , Yes, the login screen presents the NavigationController with root view, `UserTableMenuController` via a modal segue with the identifier, "Login Success".

Comment: i mean to ask how? Using interface builder or Programmatically(if so how did you write the code)?

Comment: @Neo , I used the interface builder, linked up with various segues.  Then I just use `performSegueWithIdentifier` and `perpareForSegue` to sort out where I should segue too and set delegates.  The only part that is programmatically creating views is `UserMenuTableViewController` when table cells are selected.  However that isn't within the scope of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In viewController which appears after you called your NavigationController,  call this

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

where you want to pop your navigationController. This worked for me.

Comment: That did the trick!  However I must have some logic issues, because when I call it from the `UserDashboardViewController`'s delegate method, nothing happens.  But when I call that from a dummy button I just put in my toolbar to test this line of code, it worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: Just for closure.  When the user chooses to log out from the `UserDashboardViewController`, a message is passed back to the presenting view (`UserMenuTableViewController`) via delegation, where I set a BOOL property `shouldLogOut` to YES.  In `UserMenuTableViewController`'s `viewDidAppear` method, I call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` if `shouldLogOut` is YES.  Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

A little too late but you can use unwind segues to do this, and it will unravel accordingly.